# Bash script to extract filenames from git whatchanged

Tags: git, bash

I'm trying to get a list of all the js files that changed to know what to reminify.

I previously asked [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361496/save-a-modified-log-right-before-a-commit/9361595#comment11832771_9361595) question

So far this is the best I came up with but it feels really unsafe.

```
GITCHANGES=$(git whatchanged -n 1 --pretty=format:)
I=0;
for f in $GITCHANGES;
do
    I=$(($I + 1));
    if [[ $(($I % 6 )) == 0 ]]; then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

But this gives me all the files that changed (`php` `css` `js`) and not just the `js` files

How would I get just the js files? Also is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're simply trying to reminify files, maybe you should record the modification timestamps when you minify (you could keep a list in a dotfile) and just consult that file to see what needs reminifying.

Comment: BTW, your output from `git whatchanged -n 1 --pretty=format:` is basically doing the same thing as `git diff-tree HEAD^ HEAD`, so maybe you should just use that, especially since you can do things like pass the `--name-only` flag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list all the files for a commit in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-do-i-list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git)

Comment: @Schwern: not a dupe, check the comments on the answer

Comment: @qwertymk The comments on the answer are "Thank that works perfectly" and "Thank you. Just perfect."  What am I missing?  Do you just need a `grep '\.js$'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-do-i-list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git), use `git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD^` to get a list of changed files.  Then pipe it through `grep`.

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD^ | grep '\.js$'
```

Comment: `git whatchanged -n 1 --pretty=format: --name-only | grep '\.js$'`

Comment: @qwertymk Yeah, that works better.  It'll pick the last commit in `git log` order otherwise `HEAD^` might go down the wrong side of a merge.  BTW I misunderstood which answer you were referring to above, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your script can be condensed really simply into

```
git diff-tree --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | grep '\.js$'
```

This will spit out a list of all .js files that differ between `HEAD^` (first parent) and `HEAD`.

Comment: `diff-tree` returns the directories changed, not the files.  At least not according to my tests.

Comment: I think you need a `-r` to `diff-tree`.

Comment: It also outputs the commit ID which could be accidentally be taken as a filename by the script.  You'd need to strip the first line with a `tail -n +2` which is a GNUism or put together something with `sed`.  (Sorry for the stream of corrections, I'm researching this myself)

Comment: @Schwern: Ah hrm, in my test repo the commit only touched top-level files, so I forgot about the recursion bit. In any case, with `-r` it gives precisely the right output. I see no commit ID information in the output of `git diff-tree`, nor should there be since it's just diffing trees.

Comment: @Schwern: Extra "ah hrm": It does output a commit ID if you simply say `git diff-tree -r --name-only HEAD` (i.e. only provide one tree-ish). If you provide two, it doesn't.

Comment: @KevinBallard yes, command should be `git diff-tree -r --name-only HEAD^..HEAD`